# Why my background image zoom in when i click on select input

Tags: html, css, reactjs, overflow, background-image

I´m coding a react webapp but in my Home page, when i click the select input the background image zoom in and that is not what i want. I have been thinking about what would be the problem like the overflow or maybe the way the background image is coded.

This is the WebApp https://barbozitoshop.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

If you send the code, I can comment better.
Detection without code is very difficult.
To test, when input select is clicked, give the following style to your code:

```
scale: 0.9;
```

or

```
scale: 0.8;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).